# Google line chart dual Y-axis issue

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I'm working on a dual Y-axis linechart that is to have both height and weight on the Y-axes with the date displaying on the X-axis:

I'm pulling the data from my MYSQL database and encoding it into json and the passing it to my function that draws the chart as shown:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() 
    {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Height');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
        data.addRows([ 
        <?php 
        $chart_info = $db->prepare("SELECT `height`, `weight`, `date_captured` FROM `child_results_capture` ");
        $chart_info->execute();
        $result = $chart_info->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $chart_data = '';

        foreach($result as $value)
        {
            $chart_data.="['".$value['date_captured']."',".$value['height'].",".$value['weight']."],";
            // var_dump($chart_data);exit;
            // echo $chart_data;    
        }
        echo $chart_data;
        ?> 
        ]);

        var options = {

          title: 'Height-Weight graph',

        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        series: {
          0: {axis: 'Height'},
          1: {axis: 'Weight'}
        },
        axes: {
          y: {
            Height: {label: 'Height (cm)'},
            Weight: {label: 'Weight (kg)'}
          }
        }
      };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('graph_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }   
    </script>
    <div id="graph_chart"></div>
```

The Json returned from my php bit looks like this:

```
['2016-07-27',51,3.4],['2016-08-03',52,4],['2016-08-10',53,5],['2016-08-17',54,6],['2016-08-24',55,7],['2016-08-31',56,8],
```

And my output looks like this:

[image: height weight linechart]

As shown above, I only get one Y-axis(for the height) and my chart axes are not labelled with the corresponding names

Will appreciate being pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the specific configuration options used in the question to build the *Dual-Y Chart*
are for *Material* charts only --> `google.charts.Line`

```
var optionsMatl = {
  title: 'Height-Weight graph',
  width: 900,
  height: 500,
  series: {
    0: {axis: 'Height'},
    1: {axis: 'Weight'}
  },
  axes: {
    y: {
      Height: {label: 'Height (cm)'},
      Weight: {label: 'Weight (kg)'}
    }
  }
};
```

a different set of options is needed to build a *Dual-Y Chart*
in a *Classic* chart --> `google.visualization.LineChart`

```
var optionsCore = {
  title: 'Height-Weight graph',
  width: 900,
  height: 500,
  series: {
    1: {
      targetAxisIndex: 1
    }
  },
  vAxes: {
    0: {
      title: 'Height (cm)'
    },
    1: {
     title: 'Weight (kg)'
    }
  },
  theme: 'material'
};
```

from the documentation for [Dual-Y Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#dual-y-charts)...

> In the Material code ..., the axes and series options together specify the dual-Y appearance of the chart. The series option specifies which axis to use for each. The axes option then makes this chart a dual-Y chart.
>
> In the Classic code, this differs slightly. Rather than the axes option, you will use the vAxes option (or hAxes on horizontally oriented charts). Also, instead of using names, you will use the index numbers to coordinate a series with an axis using the targetAxisIndex option.

see following working snippet, which draw both...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Height');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Weight')
  data.addRows([
    ['2016-07-27',51,3.4],
    ['2016-08-03',52,4],
    ['2016-08-10',53,5],
    ['2016-08-17',54,6],
    ['2016-08-24',55,7],
    ['2016-08-31',56,8]
  ]);

    var optionsMatl = {
      title: 'Height-Weight graph',
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      series: {
        0: {axis: 'Height'},
        1: {axis: 'Weight'}
      },
      axes: {
        y: {
          Height: {label: 'Height (cm)'},
          Weight: {label: 'Weight (kg)'}
        }
      }
    };

  var chartMatl = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div_matl'));
  chartMatl.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(optionsMatl));

    var optionsCore = {
      title: 'Height-Weight graph',
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        alignment: 'end'
      },
      series: {
        1: {
          targetAxisIndex: 1
        }
      },
      vAxes: {
        0: {
          title: 'Height (cm)',
        },
        1: {
         title: 'Weight (kg)'
        }
      },
      theme: 'material'
    };

  var chartCore = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_core'));
  chartCore.draw(data, optionsCore);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>Material Chart</div>
<div id="chart_div_matl"></div>
<div>Core Chart</div>
<div id="chart_div_core"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, personally recommend using the _Classic_ chart (`google.visualization.LineChart`) --> columns roles as well as many config options simply don't work on _Material_ charts (`google.charts.Line`)

Comment: Excellent. second time in a week you're coming to my rescue! thankyou. and agreed on Classic charts being better. I've only started using google charts recently but i'm catching up now. Last question, graph displays nicely but the (not sure what to call them) 'indicators' that show height and weight at the top(below the chart title) seem to be overlapping each other i.e written on top of each other. any idea why?

Comment: should mention this is on my part. yours display well

Comment: i _think_ you are referring to the legend -- you can use `position` and `alignment` options...? see edit above...

Comment: 'legend' was the word i was looking for :). I sorted the overlapping issue on the legend using the 'maxLines' option